# Ubuntu upgrade process failed

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, mariadb, percona-xtradb-cluster

I tried to dist-upgrade my ubuntu server on my percona cluster but it failed with this message

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libmysqlclient18 : Depends: libmariadbclient18 (= 5.5.33a+maria-1~precise) but it is not installable
```

And here is the package listing

```
# dpkg --list | grep -E 'percona|mysql'
ii  libdbd-mysql-perl                   4.020-1build2                     Perl5 database interface to the MySQL database
iU  libmysqlclient18                    5.5.33a+maria-1~precise           Virtual package to satisfy external depends
ii  mariadb-common                      5.5.33a+maria-1~precise           MariaDB database common files (e.g. /etc/mysql/conf.d/mariadb.cnf)
ii  percona-xtrabackup                  2.1.5-680-1.precise               Open source backup tool for InnoDB and XtraDB
ii  percona-xtradb-cluster-client-5.5   5.5.31-23.7.5-438.precise         Percona Server database client binaries
ii  percona-xtradb-cluster-common-5.5   5.5.33-23.7.6-496.precise         Percona Server database common files (e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf)
ii  percona-xtradb-cluster-galera-2.x   157.precise                       Galera components of Percona XtraDB Cluster
ii  percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.5   5.5.31-23.7.5-438.precise         Percona Server database server binaries
ii  php5-mysql                          5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8                 MySQL module for php5
```

During the install of the server, mariadb and galera cluster have first been installed. Then removed to be replaced by percona XtraDBCluster. So i think this is the source of the problem. But how can i resolve this without reinstalling all ?

**UPDATE 1**

```
# apt-cache policy libmariadbclient18
libmariadbclient18:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
     5.5.32+maria-1~precise 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `apt-cache policy libmariadbclient18`

Comment: Updated with `apt-cache policy libmariadbclient18` output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found the solution.

```
# wget http://www.percona.com/redir/downloads/Percona-XtraDB-Cluster/LATEST/deb/precise/x86_64/libmysqlclient18_5.5.33-23.7.6-496.precise_amd64.deb
# dpkg -i libmysqlclient18_5.5.33-23.7.6-496.precise_amd64.deb
# apt-get install -f
# apt-get upgrade
```

And all is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify that your software repository lists are in correct working order. It seems to me that APT has no access to the package you mentioned.

According to [this](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/mariadb_5.5/precise/main/base/libmariadbclient18), it's in the Maria DB PPA which APT must know about.

So put this in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mariadb.list`:

```
http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu precise main
```

and run

```
apt-get update
apt-get -d install libmysqlclient18
dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libmysqlclient18*.deb
dpkg --configure --pending
apt-get install -f
```

Comment: I still got error. dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmysqlclient18:
 libmysqlclient18 depends on libmariadbclient18 (= 5.5.33a+maria-1~precise); however:
  Package libmariadbclient18 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libmysqlclient18 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

Comment: I've updated my answer, this should fix the problem you're having with the unpacked, but yet unconfigured package.

Comment: dpkg failed `dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libmysqlclient18:
 php5-mysql depends on libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.13-1).
 libdbd-mysql-perl depends on libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.13-1).
 percona-xtradb-cluster-client-5.5 depends on libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.31-23.7.5-438.precise).`

Comment: Did you do `dpkg --configure --pending` before running `apt-get install -f`?

Comment: Yes and i got the same error.

Comment: Try this then:

apt-get update
apt-get -d libmysqlclient18
dpkg -i libmysqlclient18*.deb
dpkg --configure --pending
apt-get install -f

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11138/discussion-between-fuero-and-spin0us)

Comment: Anymore infos about my problem ?